# App rendering blank template in multi app django project

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple CRUD app that renders all its templates when i test it as the only app in a project.
It shows me a blank template however, for the same templates, when i add it to a project with a login/ out app (so that there are two apps all together)
I am sure its something i am overlooking but i cant work it out.  help!

All works with the templates in a template folder and is the default app in a project.  I use a standard settings.py and the templates section is below.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The Url is also straight forward as below

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^conform/', include('conform.urls')),
]
```

The templates are located in the apps/templates folder

Consequently, i am able to call the pages thus /conform/conform/view_name/
and it works fine.

However, if i create a new project and add a login/logout app as well as the conform app.  In the login app, i present the authenticated user with a nav bar with menu links to template pages in the conform app.

When i click on it i get a blank page!  Address shows the correct url for the view but show nothing.  I changed text in one of the templates to confirm that the app was not finding it and that seems to be the case.

The multi app settings.py templates section :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In this instance, i have one templates folder under the project folder with two folder each named after the apps.

I have tried moving them around and even putting them back in the apps folders but it still shows a blank screen.

Here is the tree of the project folder:

```
── conform
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── templates
│       └── conform
├── key
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── __pycache__
├── media
│   └── profile_pics
├── static
│   └── images
├── templates
│   └── key
└── therapy
    └── __pycache__
```

Where conform and key are the two apps in the therapy project.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION!!

I can confirm that the app is finding the template.  So this is not a configuration problem. When i rename the template file; say from a.html to b.html, django complains that its unable to find it.

So its a http kind of problem.  here is the index page i am using.

```
{% extends "key/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}


   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'conform:conform_staff_create' %}">Add Staff</a></li>
          <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'conform:conform_staff_list' %}">List Staff</a></li>
          <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'key:user_login' %}">Help</a></li>
          {% endif %}

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container">
 <div class="alert alert-info">

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h2>Hello {{ user.username }}</h2>
    <h2>Welcome to !</h2>
    <strong>Success!</strong>     
    {% else %}
        <h3>Login with a valid <strong>username</strong> and <strong>password</strong> to begin.</h3>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

when the link for 'list staff' is clicked the following template is supposed to be displayed but it shows a blank!  Can any one explain why?

```
{% extends "keys/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'conform_staff_list' %}">Staff Listing</a></p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>Link</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td>city</td>
    <td>postcode</td>
    <td>county</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td>telephone</td>
    <td>email</td>
</tr>
{% for object in object_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{object.pk}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">{{object}}</a></td>
    <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.postcode }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.county }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.country }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.telephone }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.email }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'conform_staff_create' %}">Create new Staff</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please show your project tree structure? It's showing blank page not showing the error template not found error, so may be error is in html. Check that too specially if you have base html and importing the base to other html

Comment: Thanks Sam,  All i have in the templates folder for this app is the tempates for the views.  No base etc.. That is all in the templates folder under the project folder (root)

Comment: I have resolved this problem now. Thanks.